# Как компилировать код с PySimpleGUI в python

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Попробывал копилировать код через командную строку скачав pyinstaller  командой pyinstaller -F 0.py
но файл крашится поле открытия окна с картинкой

Answer (score 1):

Добавил картинки в папку с файлом все заработало